# JavaScript API for Adobe Acrobat - how to create a relative link to a non-PDF document with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, xml-serialization, relative-path, acrobat-sdk

My company wants to set up some PDF documents to track projects. We want to create links inside the PDF that, when clicked, open a given document (.doc, .xls etc) using a relative path.

There is the app.openDoc JavaScript method, however that only works for PDF files.

There is the "Open a file" action, but that seems to work for only absolute paths.

I've looked into the API ( http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf ) to no avail ... does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJS.88.433.html) has no such method, but you can do the following:

- Convert the .doc or .xsl file to .docx or .xslx
- Attach the XML file to the PDF
- Use the [Doc.getDataObjectContents()](http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/08/base64_encode_a_pdf_attachment.html) to read the data

As an alternative, you can also use the [util.readFileIntoStream](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/getting-external-data-into-acrobat-x-javascript) method in a closed environment where you can install folder-level scripts on everyone's system.